# I2S output in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, intel-fpga, i2s

I am making an I2S output in VHDL for a project. This is my first project using VHDL and the problem may be my basic VHDL understanding.

This is my code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

entity DE0_CV is
  port (
     CLOCK_50 : in  std_logic; --clock input
     GPIO     : inout std_logic_vector(35 downto 1) --IO ports
     );  
end DE0_CV;

architecture behave of DE0_CV is
    signal WS : std_logic; --word select for I2S --word select
    signal data_left : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0); --data for I2S
    signal data_right : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0); --data for I2S

    signal CHANNEL : std_logic; -- input from ADC, used for WS

    signal clk_div_4 : std_logic;   --6.25 MHz clock
    signal clk_div_8 : std_logic;   --3.125 MHz clock
begin

    CHANNEL <= GPIO(24); -- input from ADC
    GPIO(34) <= CHANNEL; -- output to DAC

    WS <=  NOT CHANNEL;


    process(clock_50)
        variable cnt_4 : integer range 0 to 3 := 0;
        variable cnt_8 : integer range 0 to 7 := 0;
        begin

        if RISING_EDGE(CLOCK_50) then
            if cnt_8 = 7 then
                clk_div_8 <= NOT clk_div_8;
                cnt_8 := 0;
            else
                cnt_8 := cnt_8 + 1;
            end if;

            if cnt_4 = 3    then
                clk_div_4 <= NOT clk_div_4;
                cnt_4 := 0;
            else
                cnt_4 := cnt_4 + 1;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;



    process (clk_div_8)
        variable out_bit : integer range 0 to 15 := 0; 
        variable WS_state : std_logic;

        begin   

            data_right <= "1111111111111111"; --test data for right channel
            data_left <="111011101111111"; --test data for right channel

            GPIO(32) <= clk_div_8; --clk for DAC

            if WS_state /= WS AND RISING_EDGE(clk_div_8) then --if WS changes state
                WS_state := WS;
                out_bit := 0; --reset out bit
            end if;

            if RISING_EDGE(clk_div_8) then
                if WS = '1' then
                        GPIO(30) <= data_right(out_bit); --set data for DAC
                        out_bit := out_bit + 1; --change data bit
                elsif WS = '0' then
                        GPIO(30) <= data_left(out_bit); --set data for DAC
                        out_bit := out_bit + 1; --change data bit
                end if;
            end if;
    end process;
end behave;
```

When using the code, the output works partly. As seen on the follwing picture, the data is delayed every second time. This is for moth left and right channel.

[image]

How can i fix this? I don't understand why this is happening as the out_bit should reset at the same time (I think?).

Comment: What is the mapping from signals in your VHDL to signals in your picture?

Comment: Gpio(30) is Data.
Gpio(32) is Clock.
Gpio(34) is Select.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand, You have chosen synchronous design based on "clock_50".
You have generated two sub-clock from "CLOCK_50" that the clk_div_4 is not used yet. You are listening to GPIO24 as "WS" signal and after any change on it you want to reset the bit index (out_bit) and base on its value you want to set the GPIO30 synchronous with CLK_div_8 clock by data_left/data_right.

I found some coding anomalies:

1. You have set the 16 bit signal with 15 bit that is an error

   data_left <="111011101111111"; --test data for right channel
2. The concurrent command like this `GPIO(32) <= clk_div_8; --clk for DAC` is better to be out of the process.
3. Under the synchronous process, "process (clk_div_8)" you have written

   ```
       if WS_state /= WS AND RISING_EDGE(clk_div_8) then
           WS_state := WS;
           out_bit := 0; --reset out bit
       end if;
   ```

   That is not synchronous and also not good practice.
4. your bit index (out_bit) need a mechanism to prevent from being out of range.

I have changed your code a little bit and results seems good.
[image]

The changed code is this:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
entity DE0_CV is
  port (
     CLOCK_50 : in  std_logic; --clock input
     GPIO     : inout std_logic_vector(35 downto 1) --IO ports
     );  
end DE0_CV;

architecture behave of DE0_CV is
    signal WS : std_logic; --word select for I2S --word select
    signal data_left : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0); --data for I2S
    signal data_right : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0); --data for I2S

    signal CHANNEL : std_logic; -- input from ADC, used for WS

    signal clk_div_4 : std_logic;   --6.25 MHz clock
    signal clk_div_8 : std_logic := '0'; --***changed by BD_CE***  --3.125 MHz clock
begin
    CHANNEL <= GPIO(24); -- input from ADC
    GPIO(34) <= CHANNEL; -- output to DAC
    WS <=  NOT CHANNEL;

    process(clock_50)
        variable cnt_4 : integer range 0 to 3 := 0;
        variable cnt_8 : integer range 0 to 7 := 0;
        begin
        if RISING_EDGE(CLOCK_50) then
            if cnt_8 = 7 then
                clk_div_8 <= NOT clk_div_8;
                cnt_8 := 0;
            else
                cnt_8 := cnt_8 + 1;
            end if;
            if cnt_4 = 3    then
                clk_div_4 <= NOT clk_div_4;
                cnt_4 := 0;
            else
                cnt_4 := cnt_4 + 1;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    data_right <= "1111111111111111"; --test data for right channel
    data_left  <= "1110111011111111"; --***changed by BD_CE***  --test data for right channel
    GPIO(32) <= clk_div_8; --clk for DAC

    process (clk_div_8) --***changed by BD_CE***
        variable out_bit : integer range 0 to 16 := 0; --***changed by BD_CE***
        variable WS_state : std_logic;
        begin   
            if RISING_EDGE(clk_div_8) then
                if WS_state /= WS then --if WS changes state
                   WS_state := WS;
                   out_bit := 0; --reset out bit
                else 
                  out_bit := out_bit + 1; --change data bit
                  if out_bit = 16 then --***added by BD_CE***
                    out_bit := 0;
                  end if;
                end if;
                if WS = '1' then  --***changed by BD_CE***
                        GPIO(30) <= data_right(out_bit); --set data for DAC
                elsif WS = '0' then
                        GPIO(30) <= data_left(out_bit); --set data for DAC
                end if;
            end if;
    end process;

end behave;
```